# Program that generates a serie of carachtere from 1 to 1000 that includes numbers and letters

Tags: c++, bash

I would like to create a program that generates a serie of carachtere from 1 to 1000 that includes numbers and letters .
for example : 0001 0002 0003 0004 0005 0006 0007 0008 0009 000a 000b 000c 000d 000e 000f ... 000z 0010 00011 ...

Comment: Ok. Now please do explain how this relates to bash and c++, include the code you so far have written, explain what is wrong with it and also ask a *question*. Also take the [tour].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just put your digits in a string and loop through them

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

const std::string digits = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

int main()
{
    for (auto a : digits)
    {
        for (auto b : digits)
        {
            for (auto c : digits)
            {
                for (auto d : digits)
                {
                    std::cout << a << b << c << d << '\n';
                    if (a == '1') // stop at 1000
                        return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Four digits, four loops. Put whatever letters or numbers you like in digits. Add a stop condition if you wish.

There's more sophisticated ways you can do this, but the above should work for you.